# Geocodes for addresses not working for salesforce data.com

Tags: integration, data.com, data-service

I have activated the "Geocodes for Account Billing Address" for my Accounts and found few accounts updated with correct latitude and longitude, but for few accounts are having blanks in the the latitude/longitude fields. This happens for country like Bangladesh, Pakistan with correct address given.

e.g. For country India-> Mumbai its work but if I put Bangladesh -> Dhaka it does not

I have added "Data Integration Rules" in the related list for Account as given below but in the status its showing "Not Found" meaning record does not match with data service.

[image]